# Error in Crystal Report using SQL server and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am creating crystal report using visual studio 2010 and sql server 2008..
I want to show item report by using Id, as iIclicked button error is showing

Code :

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Clear();
adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from item where ITEM_ID=" + textBox1.Text + "", con);
adp.Fill(ds);
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
rd.Load(@"C:\Users\Nauman\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\GCS_SOFTWARE\GCS_SOFTWARE\CrystalReport1.rpt");
rd.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
```

When I put id like 1 or 2 error is showing like

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.

Comment: Have you created any valid item with id=1 or id=2 in your database, in order to retrieve them with the query?

Comment: Your code is a security hazard as it's vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use parameterized queries instead.